# Connectivity between access database and c#

Tags: c#, ms-access, ado.net, oledb

I was checking about access database connectivity with c# in social of MSDN where i found the sample connection string as follows

```
string ConnStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\abc.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=password";
```

Now my question is suppose i have created a form application and i put the database file abc.mdb at the same location where the .exe file resides. In that case can i write the connection string as follows?

```
string ConnStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=abc.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=password";
```

I was trying this with SQL database file but it was not running may be the full path is mandatory for this case. I'm i right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use a relative path in connection string, you can generate it at runtime something like:

string connstring = string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Persist Security Info=true", Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "MyDatabase01.accdb"));

Answer (score 0):

try, (*although not tested*)

```
string dbpath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "abc.mdb";
string ConnStr = String.Format(Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Jet OLEDB:Database Password=password;", dbpath)
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, yes, having the .mdb file in the same directory will work with your second connection string.

Assuming you meant a MSSQL or MSSQL Express in the second "question," you need to specify the SQL Server instance as part of the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

For ASP.NET 2.0 or higher, the database file (.mdb or .accdb) should always go into the App_Data folder. There are two reasons for this: first, App_Data is configured to prevent users from browsing to the folder and downloading a copy of your database. Second, you can take advantage of the special DataDirectory token (or substitution string) to reference the file within a connection string. DataDirectory defaults to the App_Data directory.

So your Access datasource goes like this.

```
<asp:AccessDataSource 
    ID="AccessDataSource1" 
    runat="server" 
    DataFile="~/App_Data/MyDb.mdb" 
    SelectCommand="Select * From MyTable">
</asp:AccessDataSource>
```

Comment: While you are correct, the OP is specifically asking about a Windows Forms app, so your answer is not really relevant...

Comment: Ohh sorry.. Got a bit hurry to answer this... :)

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this, but the [DataDirectory](http://www.connectionstrings.com/access) substitution string could be used.

```
string ConnStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\abc.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=password";
```

Then you could do

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", @"D:\MyApp");
```

As describe in the following [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=920700):

> **|DataDirectory| substitution string support**
>
> **|DataDirectory|** (enclosed in pipe symbols) is a substitution string
> that indicates the database path. Therefore, you do not have to
> include the full path in the code. When you include the full path in
> the code, you may experience problems because the full database path
> can be serialized in different locations. The |DataDirectory|
> substitution string also makes it easy to share a project and to
> deploy an application.
>
> For example, if you include the full path in the code, the application
> can have the following connection string.
>
> Data Source= c:\program files\MyApp\Mydb.sdf
>
> If you use the |DataDirectory| substitution
> string, the application can have the following connection string.
>
> Data
> Source = |DataDirectory|\Mydb.sdf
>
> To set the DataDirectory property, call the [AppDomain.SetData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.setdata.aspx) method. If you do not set the DataDirectory
> property, the following default rules are applied to access the
> database folder:
>
> - For applications that are put in a folder on the
>   user's computer, the database folder uses the application folder.
> - For
>   applications that are running under ClickOnce, the database folder
>   uses the specific data folder that is created.